# how can i read the ReferenceTo field on the FieldDefinition object

Tags: soql

I'm attempting to use queries (not describe info) to attain which fields look up to a certain object. I'm stuck trying to decode the format of the `ReferenceTo` field on `FieldDefinition`.

Sample code:

```
List<EntityDefinition> allObjects = [SELECT QualifiedApiName, (SELECT ReferenceTo,Label FROM Fields WHERE RelationshipName!=null) FROM EntityDefinition];

for (EntityDefinition thisObj : allObjects) {
    for (FieldDefinition thisField : thisObj.fields) {
        system.debug(thisField.ReferenceTo);
        // i want to check which object this lookup references
    }
}
```

Debug is returning:
`15:16:45:556 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|common.api.soap.wsdl.RelationshipReferenceTo@d7f7b38`

I'm under the impression `ReferenceTo` should be an array of strings based on the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm. How can I determine which SObject this relationship is referencing?

Comment: I found you can use the `DataType` field which will contain text like `Lookup(Account)` I can parse that string to determine the lookup object but it feels a little janky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I ran the command `sfdx force:data:soql:query --query="SELECT QualifiedApiName, (SELECT ReferenceTo,QualifiedApiName FROM Fields WHERE RelationshipName!=null LIMIT 1) FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName = 'Account' LIMIT 1" --targetusername sandbox --usetoolingapi --json`, it gave the below output:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "size": 1,
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "queryLocator": null,
    "entityTypeName": "EntityDefinition",
    "records": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "EntityDefinition",
          "url": "/services/data/v48.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityDefinition/Account"
        },
        "QualifiedApiName": "Account",
        "Fields": {
          "size": 1,
          "totalSize": 1,
          "done": true,
          "queryLocator": null,
          "entityTypeName": "FieldDefinition",
          "records": [
            {
              "attributes": {
                "type": "FieldDefinition"
              },
              "ReferenceTo": {
                "referenceTo": [
                  "Account"
                ]
              },
              "QualifiedApiName": "MasterRecordId"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We can see that `ReferenceTo` contains property named `referenceTo` and it is a string array.

When I run this `System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.FieldDefinition.fields.ReferenceTo.getType());`, it gives the output **COMPLEXVALUE** and this is not listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm)

Based on above findings, I came up with the below workaround where we can serialize and deserialize `FieldDefinition` object.

```
List<EntityDefinition> allObjects = [SELECT QualifiedApiName, (SELECT ReferenceTo,Label,QualifiedApiName FROM Fields WHERE RelationshipName!=null) FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName = 'Account'];

for (EntityDefinition thisObj : allObjects) {
    for (FieldDefinition thisField : thisObj.fields) {

        String fieldDefinitionJSONStr = JSON.serialize(thisField);
        Map<String,Object> fieldDefinitionJSONMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(fieldDefinitionJSONStr);
        Map<String,Object> referenceToJSONMap = (Map<String,Object>)fieldDefinitionJsonMap.get('ReferenceTo');
        List<Object> referenceToList = (List<Object>)referenceToJSONMap.get('referenceTo');

        if(referenceToList != NULL){
            for(Object obj: referenceToList){
                System.debug(thisField.QualifiedApiName + 'points to object: ' + (String)obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this seems like the best answer. Feels like ReferenceTo should really be a supported type. It also seems like the safest, the alternative of parsing the `DataType` field I can already foresee issues with namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Query the DataType in FieldDefinition object.. it will return output as in below..

ReferenceTo=common.api.soap.wsdl.RelationshipReferenceTo@3615056c, Label=Account, QualifiedApiName=Account__c, DataType=Lookup(Account)

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned this in a comment on my question. My main concern is parsing the `DataType` field you could run into issues with namespaced object since it appears to just show the object label not the API name